# Rails and BackboneJS destroy model backbone misinterprets response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, backbone.js

I am destroying a model in backbone and it sends the correct DELETE request. Everything is fine with the request; I even check in the chrome debugger and under network it says the request has `status 200` yet backbone calls my error function for some reason. Here is the code:

```
destroy : function() {
    new App.Views.Notice({ message: "Removing reminder...", type: "message"});
    this.model.destroy({
        success: function(model, response){
            this.close();
            new App.Views.Notice({message: "Successfully remove reminder", type:"success"});
        },

        error: function() {
            new App.Views.Notice({message: "Could not remove reminder", type:"error"});
        }
    });
},
```

In my Rails model:

```
def destroy
    note = Note.find_by_id(params[:id])
    note.destroy
end
```

(should I rendering some json here?)

Here is the request info:

```
DELETE /notes/41 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: _Notely_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTc1MTk3OGRkYzNiZGUzODY1YjYyYWM2MmNjOWZjZDViBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMXNUWGZDUkpHL1F2Um52NXB0emNsNnpmWDVVS1dmZ1RLOUtkQk9STXA2UjA9BjsARg%3D%3D--b186601186315cb3cc7aee51b92d1e2a76a8279e
```

Response info:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 94ab62df5f0b462901174ae329d37e1f
X-Runtime: 0.088005
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-01-15)
Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2013 04:25:34 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: _Notely_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTA1YWViMDI2NmZjMjI3NDM4ZDcwZjBkZjhjNWVjYzFiBjsAVA%3D%3D--507388d81c70eb937fe521749b60e7f170d15671; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Under the response tab in the Chrome debugger it also says "This request has no response data available" Should I be sending something in Rails? If so, what?

Comment: This only happens with Delete btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I am working with BackboneJS. In normal case when we call REST method in Backbone Model it will send JSON request (you can see in server console `as JSON`). What I am preferring to use is JSON response like this :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render :json => {:msg => "item deleted!"},:status => 200}
end
```

I don't really know whats the problem is because its getting 200 as response status. But to resolve this I am pasting my destroy code in Backbone(in coffee script)

```
model.destroy(
  success: (model, response, options) =>
    #do other stuff
  error: (model, response, options) =>
    #do stuff for error
)
```